# What part of my firewall is blocking io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException?

Tags: io, netty

So I got this message "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException" and I read somewhere else that I need to check my firewall, what part do I check or how would I fix this because this just happened yesterday?

I run on windows 11 so as I'm looking through the firewall section, I'm looking through and trying to figure put if it blocked it or not, and that about all I did